# how to write test case for static method using powermock

Tags: easymock, powermock, testcase

how to write test case for this?

```
Class ClassToBeTested{

    Result method(){
        //static method called here
        session session=ClassContainsStatic.staticMethod();

        //method called here
        Query query=session.createQuery();

        //method returned here
        return query.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
2. Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
3. Use PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to mock all methods of this class.
4. Use PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to replay mode.
5. Use PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to verify mode.

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic